# Proximal algorithm: dependence on the initial point

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, regularization

Consider the following minimization problem:
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}f(x),$$
where $f$ is a proper convex closed function and suppose that there exists at least one solution of the above-mentioned problem. Proximal point algorithm works choosing an initial point $x_0$ and the minimizing sequence is defined recursively by
$$x_k=\arg\,\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)+\frac{1}{2a_k}\lVert x−x_{k−1}\rVert^2,\quad\text{for any }k∈N.$$

By proximal algorithm theory, the sequence $(x_k)_k$ converges to a minimum point of $f$. There exists a connection between the limit point of $(x_k)$ and the initial point $x_0$? For example, in the Tikhonov regularization the minimizing sequence converges to the unique minimum norm element in the the set of the minimum points of $f$. There exists an analogous characterzation even for proximal algorithms?

Comment: What if $f = 0$?

Comment: If $f=0$, for each initial point $x_0$, the sequence generated by proximal algorithm is identically equal to $x_0$. So, I could think that the sequence converges to the point in $\arg\,\min f$ whose distance from the initial point is minimal. What do you think about it? @copper.hat

Comment: I think that it is unlikely to be so simple except in particular cases.